# clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c++, llvm, clang++

I'm attempting to follow the steps on https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl03.html to build the example. and I run my code on Centos.
I've ended up with the command:

```
clang++ -g -O3 toy.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core` -o toy
```

It's Ok when I include file llvm/ADT/APFloat.h and llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h, but when I include some files such as llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h, I get some errors shown as:

```
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Error.cpp.o): In function `(anonymous namespace)::ErrorErrorCategory::~ErrorErrorCategory()':
Error.cpp:(.text._ZN12_GLOBAL__N_118ErrorErrorCategoryD2Ev+0xb): undefined reference to `std::_V2::error_category::~error_category()'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Error.cpp.o): In function `(anonymous namespace)::ErrorErrorCategory::~ErrorErrorCategory()':
Error.cpp:(.text._ZN12_GLOBAL__N_118ErrorErrorCategoryD0Ev+0xf): undefined reference to `std::_V2::error_category::~error_category()'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Error.cpp.o): In function `llvm::object_deleter<(anonymous namespace)::ErrorErrorCategory>::call(void*)':
Error.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm14object_deleterIN12_GLOBAL__N_118ErrorErrorCategoryEE4callEPv+0x14): undefined reference to `std::_V2::error_category::~error_category()'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Error.cpp.o): In function `llvm::ErrorInfoBase::message[abi:cxx11]() const':
Error.cpp:(.text._ZNK4llvm13ErrorInfoBase7messageB5cxx11Ev[_ZNK4llvm13ErrorInfoBase7messageB5cxx11Ev]+0x11b): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Error.cpp.o): In function `(anonymous namespace)::ErrorErrorCategory::message(int) const':
Error.cpp:(.text._ZNK12_GLOBAL__N_118ErrorErrorCategory7messageEi+0x25): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Error.cpp.o): In function `llvm::ECError::log(llvm::raw_ostream&) const':
Error.cpp:(.text._ZNK4llvm7ECError3logERNS_11raw_ostreamE[_ZNK4llvm7ECError3logERNS_11raw_ostreamE]+0x52): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Error.cpp.o): In function `llvm::errorToErrorCode(llvm::Error)':
Error.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm16errorToErrorCodeENS_5ErrorE+0x1b): undefined reference to `std::_V2::system_category()'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Error.cpp.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN12_GLOBAL__N_118ErrorErrorCategoryE+0x28): undefined reference to `std::_V2::error_category::_M_message[abi:cxx11](int) const'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Error.cpp.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN12_GLOBAL__N_118ErrorErrorCategoryE+0x38): undefined reference to `std::_V2::error_category::default_error_condition(int) const'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Error.cpp.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN12_GLOBAL__N_118ErrorErrorCategoryE+0x40): undefined reference to `std::_V2::error_category::equivalent(int, std::error_condition const&) const'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Error.cpp.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN12_GLOBAL__N_118ErrorErrorCategoryE+0x48): undefined reference to `std::_V2::error_category::equivalent(std::error_code const&, int) const'
Host.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys16getProcessTripleB5cxx11Ev+0x35a): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const'
Host.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys16getProcessTripleB5cxx11Ev+0x371): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::resize(unsigned long, char)'
Host.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys16getProcessTripleB5cxx11Ev+0x39e): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned long)'
Host.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3sys16getProcessTripleB5cxx11Ev+0x3be): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(APInt.cpp.o): In function `llvm::APInt::toString[abi:cxx11](unsigned int, bool) const':
APInt.cpp:(.text._ZNK4llvm5APInt8toStringB5cxx11Ejb+0xb3): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

so how to solve this problem? thx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: What is the output of `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core`? The linker seems to be looking for standard library classes. Also could you add `-v` to your clang invocation to show how it calls the linker? Could the LLVM libraries you use have been linked to a different c++ standard library? Or does the version of C++ used (-std=c++XX) perhaps not match between the libraries and your invocation?